# Manual counter with limit and rest option

Tags: angularjs, ionic3

I have the following code for a manual counter. How do I get this to stop at zero so it doesn't go into minus numbers? When at zero, need a reset button to set the value back to 350. Alternatively, is there a better way to do this?

```
<body ng-app>
  <button ng-click="myCount = myCount - 1 " ng-init="myCount=350">
    Click to decrement by 1
  </button>

  <h2>
        Total Count: {{myCount}}
  </h2>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three methods:

1. Instead of calling pure js code in `ng-click`you can simply call a function in the controller
2. You can disable the button with `ng-disabled="myCount === 0"` when the variable reaces 0
3. You can put a one-line if in the expression `myCount = (myCount === 0) ? 0 : myCount - 1`. That reads exactly as `if(myCount === 0){ myCount = 0}else{myCount = myCount - 1}`

For more expansion in the future i recommend solution 1 combined with 2 for UX.

For the reset button you can put it whit an `ng-show` when `myCount === 0`. Be carefull that `ng-if` won't work since clicking would remove the button from the DOM before the action takes place and so angular prevents it.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app>
  <button 
  ng-click="myCount = (myCount === 0) ? 0 : myCount - 1" 
  ng-init="myCount=5" 
  ng-disabled="myCount === 0">
        Click to decrement by 1
      </button>
  <h2>
    Total Count: {{myCount}}
  </h2>
  <button ng-click="myCount = 5" ng-show="myCount === 0">Reset</button>
</body>
```